# Xcode 8.1 - How to Update Frames for All Views in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8

In Xcode 8.1, I can update for each view in the storyboard by clicking on the "Update Frames" button. But I want to update all views, how I can do that?

Comment: where do you see "update frame" ? i can't even find update frame anymore

Comment: @DavidSeek look at the bottom-right of your storyboard, there're five buttons. The "Update Frames" button looks like a reload icon, it's on the left of the "Embed In Stack" button.

Comment: oh yeah. now i see it. thanks pal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to update the frames hierarchically. If you select the main view or even the view controller and press the button, it will update frames for all child views.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 15):

They added one standalone button to the leftmost side in the constraints controls  (it looks like a refresh button). And you can also look for "Update Frames", from the toolbar and selecting Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Update Frames if you want you can select "Apply to all views in container" as before.[image]. for you reference attaching screenshots.

[Update frames example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8eifSFeYE8&feature=em-share_video_user)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you update frames when you have warnings about misplaced views. In this case, you can simply check the "Apply for all views in container" checkbox at the bottom of popup (which appears when you try to solve your warnings in the Document Outline) before pressing "Update Frames"

Comment: No, I mean that I can't find any buttons for updating frame of all views as the previous version.