# Xcode constrains goes to the wrong side

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints, ios11

I have a weird problem. The definition of middle is somehow "middle-right"

But by starting the program, everything seems right again..

Start:
[image: Start (picture)]

Here:
[image: Here <- (picture)]

Edit:

(After Honey suggested that I update the frames)

There is nothing to click on :'). The 'update frames' button is still greyed out!

[In Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrkO.png)

[In 'Editor' (Xcode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoEJc.png)

Comment: change your _trailing_ constraint from `16` to `-16`

Comment: thank you hm, but then it makes no sence :') I have the exact same coordinates in another app and there is nothing wrong.

Comment: does it solve your problem?

Comment: nope, it changed absolutely nothing :/

Comment: do you mean it doesn't show correct in storyboard, but once you run the app, it's correct?

Comment: yes, that's why I am so confused :c

Comment: and because I have the same exact settings in another app, just that there everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

So when you work from storyboard, if you write constraints, then you're all good. Once the app **runs** it will calculate the constraints and present the view.

However right from the storyboard the constraints don't get calculated immediately. If you want that to happen, you have to update the frames. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656992/5175709) answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far! But there are no frames to update. c:

Comment: I think there should be, if not, then I don't know any better. Sorry

Comment: curious did you just click on that button to update frames? What happened? Make sure you have already clicked on the viewController and then click. To do that you have to click on the top part of the scene of the viewController. I mean that yellow circle

Comment: I've added a answer for adding pictures

Comment: 1. you shouldn't add an answer, rather you should edit your question. Please delete your answer. 2. did u click on the viewcontroller? That yellow circle?

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. (: Yes, I've clicked on the yellow circle in the viewController.